# VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_login_manager alternatives to busybox

Tags: yocto

The `VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_login_manager` variable is used to determine the software to use for the user login on the target image. It is per default set to `busybox`.

Within my image I want to use coreutils and systemd - which generally works fine. However, because of the default for this variable, busybox still gets included and used in my image. How can I tell Yocto to use the login kit provided by systemd?

The only alternative value I found was tinylogin, which is [long deprecated](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/commit/meta?id=c31537a06293cb86e3087736a152fa7b81b5c7ba). I tried `"systemd"` and `"coreutils"` but with no success - both display the login but throw a `Cannot execute` error after I enter the password.

I also stumbled upon the `consolekit` recipe - which requires x11 as `DISTRO_FEATURE`. I do not want this in my image as I do not need it.

So, my question is (apart from busybox and tinylogin):
**What are valid values for the VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_login_manager variable?**

Comment: Please try VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_login_manager = "shadow". The package which assign to VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_login_manager should provide /bin/login.

Comment: @Kai Thanks for the tip! Tried it - `/bin/login` exists as symlink to `/bin/login.shadow` which exists as well, but I only get "Cannot Execu" displayed after entering username and password when trying to login.

Comment: I rebuild the version with the default (busybox) login_manager setting and copied the `login.shadow` that was created with your (shadow) config into the home directory of the working image, just to see what would happen. If I execute `~/login.shadow` I get prompted with a working login. `diff /bin/login.shadow ~/login.shadow` shows no differences, the problem seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: The following configurations from meta-yocto/conf/local.conf.sample.extended which should work with systemd. If still `Cannot execute`, I doubt it is not the configure related.
`# Use systemd for system initialization

DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"
DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED += "sysvinit"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = "systemd-compat-units"
`

Answer (score 1):

The answer, and I've confirmed this on sumo, and it should be good on anything else where we make use of VIRTUAL-RUNTIME like this, is that @Kai was close, we need to do:

```
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_login_manager = "shadow-base"
```

as what we need to provide here is not the recipe name but rather the package name to install and currently we have shadow's /bin/login put in to the shadow-base package.